# How to debug ITK c++ code in visual studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, vtk, itk

How can I debug the .cxx file in visual studio? I used CMake to configure it with ITK. I built the code and I am able to run the .exe file from windows command prompt. But I am not able to debug it. I also tried inserting sleep(10000) command at every breakpoint.

The file I am trying to debug is in the following [link for code](https://itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Examples/SimpleOperations/WidthHeight)

Comment: Make sure the .pdb files for ITK are in the same folder as the ITK .dlls. Also make sure you did not move the source for ITK.

Comment: can u please elaborate? I have .pdb files in the build folder. But where can I? find .dlls?

Comment: if you don't know that you probably built itk as static libraries. And no before you ask compiling ITK as static libraries is not your problem.

Comment: Check your output window in Visual Studio for PDB / symbol warnings about ITK. Ignore the pdb warnings about the OS.

Comment: Have you tried the built-in VS run option (F5) instead of the command line? This triggers the break points.